# Add Y/N flag to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

Trying to add a flag function to a CSV.  Basically, if I put in:

```
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Flag
```

I get the message:

```
The Value parameter is required for a member of type "NoteProperty". Specify the
Value parameter when adding members of this type.
Value:
```

The only thing I want to do is change the message.  I'd like it to say for the current line item's field, called `SO`, "Flag $_.SO?  y/n".  Meaning if the `SO` field for this line item is `Ticket007`, instead of the default message, I want it to display the message:

```
Flag Ticket007?  y/n
```

I can't figure out how to even qualify this question well enough to do a reasonable search.  `Read-Host` can't go there and setting a variable earlier in the script didn't work (tried both anyway).

Comment: Are you saying that you want it to prompt you for each item, asking if you want to flag that item based on the `SO` property of that item?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yes.  Instead of that question it asks, I want it to ask me if I want to flag the SO, and I want to be able to type in the answer, like you do if you don't declare a value for the noteproperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to loop through each item in a CSV file, and for that line item be prompted regarding if you should flag that specific item based on the value of the `SO` property of that item. In order to do that you would want to use a loop of some sort, something like:

```
$MyCSV = Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File.csv | ForEach {
    Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Flag' -NotePropertyValue ((Read-Host "Flag $($_.so)? (y/n)") -match 'y') -Pass
}
```

That will load the CSV, and for each item prompt you if you want to flag that item. It adds the `Flag` property with True/False depending on your input, and passes the new item down the pipeline.

Comment: Getting closer!  While this works, It's now creating two entries for each line.  So now Ticket007 shows up twice in the output.  I removed the `-match 'y'` and appropriate parentheses and the `-Pass` and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

As the message is telling you, you need to add a value parameter to you `Add-member`. Something like this:

```
Import-Csv your_file.csv | % {
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Flag -Value @('', "Flag $($_.SO)? y/n")[$_.SO -ne 'default']
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  A step in the right direction, but this creates the flag value as "Flag Ticket007?  y/n" whereas I'm asking how I make it ask that as a question instead of what it asks me now...